# What does the Java specification mean when it says that interfaces can be used to add methods to Object?

Tags: java, interface

In the introduction to Chapter 9, the Java Language Specification says:

"Programs can use interfaces to make it unnecessary for related classes to share a common abstract superclass **or to add methods to Object.**"

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html

What does the bolded section mean?  How can one use an interface to add methods to Object?

To be clear, I'm not asking for an explanation of what an interface is, or an explanation of the non-bolded section of the quoted sentence, only an explanation of what is meant by "add methods to Object".

Comment: could it be referring to default methods in interfaces? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't say that. It says they can be used *to make it unnecessary* to add methods to `Object`.

Comment: But it's not only unnecessary, it's impossible... why did they say that? I'm confused by that quote.

Comment: Consider `Comparable`. Without the interface facility, it would have been impossible to add it to Java, other than by making it a superclass, or adding `compareTo()` to `Object`.

Comment: Yes, I understand but still even if it were necessary it's not possible to add all the methods you might ever need to `Object`... I don't know, still looks like a weird thing to say in the jls.

Comment: That makes sense to me.  I was just confused by the wording of the sentence and got stuck on my initial incorrect interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not worded the best at all. In layman terms, it's a layer that allows you to write method signatures that your classes must fulfill in addition to what the object class has. So when your class extends the object class it isn't only required to fulfill the contract of the default methods - hashing, to string, etc; it's also required to fulfill methods of whatever interface(s) it inherits. Helps organization, architecture, sanity, etc.